# LaTeX does not finish compiling (infinite loop, maybe) when I place multiple \tl_use commands inside the \bool_until_do loop

Tags: expl3, latex3, loops, programming, auxiliary-files

I am trying to retrieve data from a .aux file using expl3.
I want to ignore the first line because it serves a different purpose (hence the \ior_str_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_tmpa_tl). The following lines always come in multiples of three: Section number, section name, and page where the section begins. My problem is that if I use more than one \tl_use inside the loop, it seems that the loop does not terminate (it should terminate when the file reading is completed).

Below is the code:

```
\file_if_exist:nTF {cap-\thechapter.aux}{
        \ior_new:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
        \ior_open:Nn \l_seccion_lista_ior {cap-\thechapter.aux}
        \ior_str_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_tmpa_tl
        \bool_until_do:nn {\ior_if_eof_p:N \l_seccion_lista_ior}{
            \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_numero_tl
            \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_nombre_tl
            \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_pagina_tl
            \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_numero_tl 
            \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl 
            \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_pagina_tl
            \tl_use:N \l_seccion_numero_tl
            \tl_use:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl
            \tl_use:N \l_seccion_pagina_tl
            %[\l_seccion_numero_tl]~\l_seccion_nombre_tl~ (p.~\l_seccion_pagina_tl)\par
        }
        \ior_close:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
    }{}
```

And an example content of the .aux file:

```
{\bool_gset_true:N \g_seccion_introduccion_bool}
{1.1}
{Tasas de cambio}
{2}
{1.2}
{Elasticidad puntual de la demanda}
{12}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: It is hard to debug such a fragment out of context, please provide a small test document

Comment: as your aux file has `{\bool_gset_true:N \g_seccion_introduccion_bool}` are you reading it with expl3 conventions? if so there is no `\endlinechar` or spaces so you shouldn't need to trim

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It doesn't matter, because that line is discarded.

Comment: well it does matter as we have to guess how the file is being read if you don't show any code @egreg your answer  assumes expl3 not on force, which may be true but.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The line is read as a string

Comment: yes but the par at the end  which is the real issue doesn't happen in expl3 mode which was why I asked how it's input @egreg

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since the file is supposed to contain text…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `\tl_use:N` into `\tl_show:N` you get

```
> \l_seccion_numero_tl={1.1}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

?
> \l_seccion_nombre_tl={Tasas de cambio}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

?
> \l_seccion_pagina_tl={2}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

?
> \l_seccion_numero_tl={1.2}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

?
> \l_seccion_nombre_tl={Elasticidad puntual de la demanda}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

?
> \l_seccion_pagina_tl={12}.
<recently read> }

l.41 \readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

?
> \l_seccion_numero_tl=\par .
<recently read> }
```

Do you see what happens? There is an implicit blank line at the end of the file and you want to check for it.

Add the test.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
{\bool_gset_true:N \g_seccion_introduccion_bool}
{1.1}
{Tasas de cambio}
{2}
{1.2}
{Elasticidad puntual de la demanda}
{12}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
\tl_const:Nn \c_seccion_par_tl { \par }

\NewDocumentCommand{\readauxfile}{m}
 {
  \file_if_exist:nT {#1}
   {
    \ior_open:Nn \l_seccion_lista_ior {#1}
    % discard the first line
    \ior_str_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_tmpa_tl
    % read the rest
    \bool_until_do:nn {\ior_if_eof_p:N \l_seccion_lista_ior}
     {
      \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_numero_tl
      % check if empty line
      \tl_if_eq:NNF  \l_seccion_numero_tl \c_seccion_par_tl
       {
        \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_nombre_tl
        \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_pagina_tl
        \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_numero_tl 
        \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl 
        \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_pagina_tl
        [\l_seccion_numero_tl]~\l_seccion_nombre_tl\c_space_tl (p.~\l_seccion_pagina_tl)\par
       }
     }
    \ior_close:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

Adapt to your setting. Beware that `~` after `\l_seccion_nombre_tl` is ignored, I used `\c_space_tl`.

[image]

A different strategy that avoids the problem of the final implicit empty line:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
{\bool_gset_true:N \g_seccion_introduccion_bool}
{1.1}
{Tasas de cambio}
{2}
{1.2}
{Elasticidad puntual de la demanda}
{12}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
\seq_new:N \l_seccion_items_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\readauxfile}{m}
 {
  \file_if_exist:nT {#1}
   {
    \ior_open:Nn \l_seccion_lista_ior {#1}
    \seq_clear:N \l_seccion_items_seq
    % discard the first line
    \ior_str_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_tmpa_tl
    % read the rest
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_seccion_lista_ior
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_seccion_items_seq { ##1 }
     }
    \ior_close:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_seccion_items_seq
     {
      \int_case:nn { \int_mod:nn { ##1 } { 3 } }
       {
        {1}{ [\tl_trim_spaces:n { ##2 }] ~ }
        {2}{ \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##2 } ~ }
        {0}{ (p.\nobreakspace\tl_trim_spaces:n { ##2 })\par }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\readauxfile{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

This solution is also more robust with respect to improper files that haven't the required number of lines (a multiple of 3 plus 1).

Comment: Molte grazie, Enrico! Sto iniziando con expl3 e pensavo ci fosse qualcosa che non stavo capendo. Ho già avuto questo problema una volta in plain TeX perché sfugge alla mia intuizione, ma ero riuscito a risolverlo. Eccolo di nuovo, ahah!

Comment: @JonatánO.Perren I added a different strategy for the problem, using an indexed map, so you can use different output for each line according if it is the first, second or third of a group.

Answer (score 0):

The TeXbook says in Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros):

> To get input from an open file, you say
> `\read⟨number⟩to⟨control sequence⟩`
> and the control sequence is defined to be a parameterless macro whose replacement text is the contents of the next line read from the designated file. This line is converted to a token list, using the procedure of Chapter 8, based on the current category codes.
> Additional lines are read, if necessary, until an equal number of left and right braces has been found. **An empty line is implicitly appended to the end of a file that is being `\read`**.

Notice the sentence **An empty line is implicitly appended to the end of a file that is being `\read`**.

The implicitly appended empty line yields an additional iteration of your loop where

- `\l_seccion_numero_tl` is empty due to the implicitly appended line being empty.
- `\l_seccion_nombre_tl` holds the quark `\q_no_value`.
- `\l_seccion_pagina_tl`  holds the quark `\q_no_value`.

In this iteration the directive `\tl_use:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl` yields the quark `\q_no_value`.
A property of a quark is that expanding the token which forms the quark yields the quark.
Expanding `\q_no_value` yields `\q_no_value`.
Thus attempts at expanding `\q_no_value` lead TeX into an infinite loop.

Probably you can do the `\tl_use:N`-thingies only in case the end of the file was not reached
while doing `\ior_get:NN` :

File: **cap-1.aux** - seems in your scenario the file is read while `\ExplSyntaxOn` is in effect, thus use `~` for obtaining normal space tokens:

```latex
{\bool_gset_true:N \g_seccion_introduccion_bool}
{1.1}
{Tasas~de~cambio}
{2}
{1.2}
{Elasticidad~puntual~de~la~demanda}
{12}
```

Minimal verifiable reproducible complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\chapter{whatsoever}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\file_if_exist:nTF {cap-\thechapter.aux}{
        % Don't do \ior_new:N within a macro's replacement text 
        % unless you want another `\read`-handle allocated whenever
        % carrying out an instance of that macro!
        \ior_new:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
        \ior_open:Nn \l_seccion_lista_ior {cap-\thechapter.aux}
        \ior_str_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_tmpa_tl
        \bool_until_do:nn {\ior_if_eof_p:N \l_seccion_lista_ior}{
            \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_numero_tl
            \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_nombre_tl
            \ior_get:NN \l_seccion_lista_ior \l_seccion_pagina_tl
            \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_numero_tl 
            \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl 
            \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_seccion_pagina_tl
%             \tl_show:N \l_seccion_numero_tl
%             \tl_show:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl
%             \tl_show:N \l_seccion_pagina_tl
            \ior_if_eof:NF \l_seccion_lista_ior {
              \tl_use:N \l_seccion_numero_tl \\
              \tl_use:N \l_seccion_nombre_tl \\
              \tl_use:N \l_seccion_pagina_tl \\
              %[\l_seccion_numero_tl]~\l_seccion_nombre_tl~ (p.~\l_seccion_pagina_tl)\par
            }
        }
        \ior_close:N \l_seccion_lista_ior
    }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thankssss, Ulrich! :D